# Using React Router within child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-router

I'm using React Router in my React app, and from the App Component, all my Routes work as expected.

However, I'm trying to user React Router to render a component in a child of App Component. When the user navigates to "/admin" the Router successfully renders the Admin Component. Now, within the Admin Component I'd like to match the route "/admin/posts/new" to render the NewPost Component (a child of Admin).

I'm importing all necessary files, and no errors are thrown, but the app doesn't render the NewPost Component when visiting "/admin/posts/new". I've dug around the webs and couldn't find anything relevant to this issue, but I'm new to React and I might not have the language to be searching for the correct things. Any help is appreciated! Below is Admin Component. Thanks!

```
import React from 'react';
import './index.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import NewLabelPost from './NewLabelPost'

const logOut = () => {
  firebase.auth().signOut();
}

const Admin = () =>
  <Router>
    <div>
      <h3>Musique Plastique Admin Portal</h3>
      <div className="actions">
        <ul>
          <li className="blue" onClick={logOut}>Log out</li>
          <li className="blue"><Link to={`/admin/posts/new`}>Add a new Label Post</Link></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={`/admin/posts/new`} render={() => <NewLabelPost />}/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
export default Admin;
```

Comment: please post the code for the AdminComponent where you have the routes for `/admin/posts/new`

Comment: Hard to debug without code but are you using `<Switch>` by any chance? Switch will render exclusively, meaning the first thing it matches. Maybe you're using switch with two Routes `/admin` and `/admin/posts/new` inside of it?

Comment: @coolboyjules great point. I am using Switch. I'll look into that now.

Comment: @palsrealm I'll the original question to include that now.

Comment: can you post the routes that lead to admin being loaded?